# placeholder size and location in android directory

Tags: android

I have placeholder jpg images of size 500x500 which I'm using in UIL as drawables.

Where should I place them in res folder. Do I need to create different resolution sizes and store in hdpi, mdpi, etc. If yes, then what should be its dimensions?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You can place those placeholder images in your drawable folder.

As far as different resolution assets, you can place just like a normal drawable.

Check link provided by @Blundell. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html